# What is meaning of "Row Total" in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I always get confused about `Row total` in Magento.

Can anyone explain what this term means and how it is calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Row total is calculated per order item.

Calculation of **Row Total** as below

```
$_item->getBaseRowTotal() + $_item->getBaseTaxAmount() + $_item->getBaseHiddenTaxAmount() + Mage::helper('weee')->getBaseRowWeeeAmountAfterDiscount($_item) - $_item->getBaseDiscountAmount()
```

Equation as below

```
Row Total = ((ordered item price * ordered item qty) + Tax) - Discount
```

For more info look in below file

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

Comment: i have same problem in magento2 .1 can you help me regarding this